# Python remove dynamic substring from string

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to remove dynamic substring from string. e.g.:

```
Item value1="001" value2="abc" value3="123xyz"
```

and i need output:

```
Item value1="001"  value3="123xyz"
```

I mean I need remove value2="abc". value2 is an unique element and can be placed anywhere in original string. "abc" is dynamic variable and can have various length. What is the fastest solution of this problem? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tagged this with regex. Soon the regex-sharks come.

Comment: Do you really need the _fastest_ solution? Because writing custom C code is going to beat any regex or str-method solution, even if only by a few nanoseconds, but does that actually matter?

Comment: Regular expression is also fine

Answer (score 1):

regex should be pretty fast in this case:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'value2="\w+"\s?')
re.sub(p, '', 'Item value1="001" value2="abc" value3="123xyz"')
```

*the above works assuming the value for `value2` has only alphabets (i.e. no digits or space-like charaters*

Answer (score 1):

You could try a list comprehension

```
a='Item value1="001" value2="abc" value3="123xyz"'
print(' '.join([e for e in a.split(" ") if not e.startswith('value2="')]))
```

Comment: `not e.startswith('value2=')` should be a little faster in this approach